# Android Testing: What do to when nothing has an id?

Tags: java, android, robotium, android-testing

I'm trying to write some automation scripts for an app I have. I've done the tutorial on Robotium's site and have a basic understanding on how I can automation. However from what I can tell regarding the app I'm testing is by using the android hierarchy viewer I see that all of the views have no ids that were explicitly defined. [image: Sample Hierarchy]

As you can see from the screen capture there are views upon nested views. The IDs for them read like 0x17e0 or 0x17de. How can I reference these, specifically, in a robotium script? The end result is I'm trying to get it to fire a click even on one of the Text Switcher views. So far I've only been able to make it work if I give it a pixel point to go to, or if I give it the text that appears in the button (but the text is dynamic and would make for a poor test).

Do I have to use the getCurrentViews() to filter down to the text switchers? Or do I have to figure out a way to traverse the entire tree going from FrameLayout>RelativeLayout>FrameLayout>LinearLayout>TextSwitcher ?

If I have to traverse the entire tree how do I get view upon view upon view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I couldn't get the ViewGroup() and getChildAt() methods to work for me I ended up doing something different:

```
// Grabbing all the LinearLayout views found under view with with id of 'content' 
ArrayList<LinearLayout> linearLayouts = solo.getCurrentViews(LinearLayout.class, solo.getView(R.id.content));

// The 4th item in the linearLayouts list is the one I need
View pickerList = linearLayouts.get(3);

// Grabbing the buttons in the pickerList
ArrayList<TextSwitcher> buttons = solo.getCurrentViews(TextSwitcher.class,pickerList);

// Now I can click on the buttons
solo.clickOnView(buttons.get(0));
```

I will say this is slow. It takes about 10 seconds for the first button click to fire. But once it goes it flys.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote to say you really probably want to get some IDs added somehwere in the hierarchy, it is a one line change that will make your life a hell of a lot easier.

But i am not without help if for some reason you cannot get this done, to do this you are going to have to walk the entire to get to the view you want.

Getting the top level view, you will be able to cast it into a ViewGroup. ViewGroups have a method called getChildAt() which you can then use to get a child at a given index, the index is 0 based and will match what you see in the hierarchy viewer so you can chain together theses commands to get to the view you want to interact with.

Comment: I was afraid that might have been the case. In my instance above, using that ViewGroup, can I cast LinearLayout(on the right side) and then get the TextSwitchers as chid groups or do I have to start from the LinearLayout on the left and go all the way to it?

Comment: You can get the FrameLayout that has an id (content) it will probably be an android built in id with a name like that so will come from the android.R.id.content rather than from your own apps package. Remember once you get to the linear layout you can save a reference to that view and then in the future traverse just from there to the textswitchers.

Comment: You got me thinking in the right direction though I couldn't for some reason get view groups to work; I'm most certainly using it wrong. I ended up using getCurrentViews and filtered on LinearLayout.class sending all that to an ArrayList. `ArrayList<LinearLayout> linearLayouts = solo.getCurrentViews(LinearLayout.class, solo.getView(R.id.content));` I then figured out index #3 is the correct LinearLayout I need. I then did the same thing to find each of the TextSwitcher views. Finally using solo.clickOnView() for each of those views.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Robodtium very much, but i know that [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) does exactly what you want. Here is a code snippet that dumps Id of the home view:

```
ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()).traverse(transform=ViewClient.TRAVERSE_CIT)
```

Here is the result dump:

```
com.android.launcher2.CellLayout id/cell3 None
     com.android.launcher2.ShortcutAndWidgetContainer NO_ID None
         com.android.launcher2.BubbleTextView NO_ID Email
         com.android.launcher2.LauncherAppWidgetHostView NO_ID None
             android.widget.AnalogClock id/0x7f0f0014 None
         com.android.launcher2.BubbleTextView NO_ID Camera
         com.android.launcher2.BubbleTextView NO_ID Settings
         com.android.launcher2.BubbleTextView NO_ID Gallery
         com.android.launcher2.LauncherAppWidgetHostView NO_ID None
             android.widget.LinearLayout id/0x7f080167 None
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll give that a shot, though if I come up with NO_ID or even where I get something like id/0x7f080167 how do I reference that? getView(R.id.0x7f080167) ?

Comment: These ids are not a good thing to use, they will be regenerated at some point in the future and so cannot be relied on. IDs in android are auto generated at build time and stored in an R file.